# How to call two HTML files depending on device orientation

Tags: javascript, html, ipad

I am calling two HTML files from JavaScript function I want that when iPad is in portrait  mode it should load `portrati.html` and in landscapde mode it should open `ladnscape.html`

Using following code it works on browser when we load first time but when we change orientation it does not change the file.

```
<SCRIPT language="JavaScript">
 if(window.innerHeight < window.innerWidth){
    window.location="Landscape/index.html";
} 
else if (window.innerHeight > window.innerWidth){
    window.location="Potrait/index.html";
}
</SCRIPT>
```

Comment: As per your code it run once when page is load

Comment: See this may be help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5284878/how-do-i-correctly-detect-orientation-change-using-javascript-and-phonegap-in-io

Comment: This might help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3495678/how-to-find-out-if-ipad-is-in-landscape-portrait-mode-in-javascript-jquery

Comment: but where to define the html file for different orientation?

Comment: See this post:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2740857/ipad-doesnt-trigger-resize-event-going-from-vertical-to-horizontal

Answer (score 1):

Safari on iOS has an event:

```
window.onorientationchange
```

You can use that for detecting changes.

```
window.onorientationchange = function() {
    switch (window.orientation) {
        case 0: // portrait
            window.location = "Portrait/index.html";
            break;
        case 90: // Landscape
            window.location = "Landscape/index.html";
            break;
        case -90: // Other way round
            window.location = "OtherLandscape/index.html";
            break;
    }
}
```

This only runs since iOS 4. If you're using an older version, you should use the onresize-Event:

```
window.onresize = function() {
     if(window.innerHeight < window.innerWidth){
         window.location="Landscape/index.html";
     } 
     else if (window.innerHeight > window.innerWidth){
         window.location="Potrait/index.html";
     }
}
```

Copy-Pasta of your code.

Comment: i tried this code but this is not working. its shows nothing on browser.

Comment: Please try to log before the switch and in each case. I don't have an iPad here to check this code.
Which iOS are you running?
I edited my post to make it more complete.